# PDFmake long text goes to next page

Tags: pdfmake

I have the following code. (I hope that is possible to infer how to solve my problem from it). I don't want that the long text goes to the next page.

```
 private dadosTotalizacao(rcms: Rcms): {}[] {
    let valor_total = 0;
    // let qtd_total = 0;
    let menor_global = 0;

    for (let item of rcms.itens) {
      let menor = 0
      let qntCotaValidas = 0
      let valorSomadoCotaValidas = 0

      if (item.cotacoes && item.cotacoes.length > 0) {
        let cotacao_ordenada = item.cotacoes
          .sort((a, b) => a.valor_unitario <= 0 ? -1 : (a.valor_unitario - b.valor_unitario))
        menor = cotacao_ordenada.find(a => a.valor_unitario > 0).valor_unitario
      }
      menor_global += +menor * +item.quantidade;

      item.cotacoes.map(cotacao => {
        if (cotacao.valor_unitario && +cotacao.valor_unitario > 0) {
          qntCotaValidas++
          valorSomadoCotaValidas += +cotacao.valor_unitario * +item.quantidade
        }
      })

      valor_total += +valorSomadoCotaValidas / +qntCotaValidas
      // let menor = item.cotacoes && item.cotacoes.length > 0 ? item.cotacoes
      //   .sort((a, b) => a.valor_unitario <= 0 ? -1 : (a.valor_unitario - b.valor_unitario)).find(a => a.valor_unitario > 0) : 0

      // for (let cotacao of item.cotacoes) {
      //   if (cotacao.valor_unitario && cotacao.valor_unitario > 0) {
      //     valor_total += +cotacao.valor_unitario * +item.quantidade;
      //     qtd_total++;
      //   }
      // }
    }

    const conteudo: any[] = [
      [{
        text: `APURAÇÃO TOTAL DE MENOR CUSTO:  R$        ${this.funcaoService.convertToBrNumber(menor_global)}`,
        border: [true, false, true, false], bold: true
      },],
      [{
        // text: `APURAÇÃO TOTAL DE CUSTO MÉDIO:  R$        ${this.funcaoService.convertToBrNumber(qtd_total > 0 ? (valor_total / qtd_total) : 0)}`,
        // border: [true, false, true, false], bold: true
        text: `APURAÇÃO TOTAL DE CUSTO MÉDIO:  R$        ${this.funcaoService.convertToBrNumber(valor_total)}`,
        border: [true, false, true, false], bold: true
      },],
      [{ text: `Observação:`, border: [true, false, true, false], margin: [0, 0, 0, 0] }],
      [{ text: ` long text here
    
       `, border: [true, false, true, false] }]
    ];

    return [{
    
      table: {
        dontBreakRows: true,
  
        widths: ['*' , 200, 10],
        body: conteudo
      }
    }];
  }
```

Image of my layout.

[image]